# Why can't I :require :refer in clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, clojurescript

See: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure#namespaces

It bothers me that idiomatic clojure is:

```
(ns clojure-example
  (:require [clojure.set :refer [union]]))
```

But idiomatic clojurescript is:

```
(ns clojurescript-example
  (:use [clojure.set :only [union]]))
```

Of course, the clojurescript code would work in clojure as well, but that brings out demons who say I should use `require` with `:refer` instead!

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually ClojureScript does support `:require :refer` and has supported it for a long while ([here's my commit](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/commit/9179a355a87021a8011ff9f0b32a4db8ee22dfcd) introducing support for `:refer` from 12 Jun 2012). <strike>That wiki page is out of date.</strike> I have edited the section on namespaces on the wiki to bring it up to date.

As for what is idiomatic, there are of course people who dislike `:use`, but that hardly makes it unidiomatic after several years of production use. You're free to make up your own mind as to whether you prefer `:require :refer` or not.

(Although the use case where `:use` actually offers capabilities that `:require` does not -- pulling in several namespaces with `(:use lib.foo lib.bar lib.quux)` -- is indeed not supported in ClojureScript, by design.)

Comment: NB. the same commit adds support for skipping `:as` in `:require` libspecs, as well as the use of symbols as libspecs (`lib.foo` being equivalent to `[lib.foo]` -- no `:as`, no `:refer`).